# Adding stackless threading to BSD Kernel?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, kernel, freebsd

[IronPort](http://www.ironport.com/) developed a stackless threading model that allows the IronPort appliance to support more than 10,000 simultaneous connections in contrast to the 100 connections supported on a traditional OS.

If one wanted to do the same but to make it open source, where should they start?

Comment: Which particular OS can't handle more than 100 connections? Every OS I know of can handle thousands of connections easily, as long as your threading code is sane (ie. not a thread per socket)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904707/incorporating-i-o-driven-scheduling-into-os-kernel

Comment: The 100 connections was taken directly from the IronPort web page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some implementations already available.  Just do some digging around and you can find them.  One of the most prevalent implementations is available under a BSD license: [Protothreads](http://www.sics.se/~adam/pt/)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is coroutines
http://www.nightmare.com/~rushing/copython/index.html