# Incorporating I/O driven scheduling into OS Kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, kernel, freebsd

[IronPort](http://www.ironport.com/) developed a high performance file system and an I/O driven scheduler optimized for the asynchronous nature of messaging (hence "Async"OS).

If you wanted to do the same but make it open source, what exactly would need to change?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904700/adding-stackless-threading-to-bsd-kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably mostly marketing - FreeBSD already handles "asynchronous nature of messaging" rather well. They most likely short-circuited some processing in the network stack for their specific purposes, same for the file system.